# include a model class outside rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm writing a test script outside Rails for querying a mysql database.
all I have is 'Product' model class and its corresponding data table in the database.
I know that it can be done exactly in the way that the below script demonstrates.
I simply put require 'active_record' and 'mysql2' here to get it accessible.

```
require 'active_record'
require 'mysql2' 


ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  'mysql2', # or 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3'
  host:     'localhost',
  database: 'your_database',
  username: 'your_username',
  password: 'your_password'
)


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  #blah, blah, blah
end

# Now instantiating and do some stuff
puts Product.all
product = Product.new
```

but, purposely, I don't want to repeatedly declare a model class like what I've done with the Product model like above. 
what do i do to just reference that model programatically on the top of the file, something like "require 'product'"? Is that valid?
so I don't bother copying a model definition over to this test script, especially when the model has quite long content.

Comment: Yes, `require 'product'` should be all right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'active_record'
require 'mysql2' 

require 'path/to/class.rb'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  'mysql2', # or 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3'
  ...
```